# How to get particular words to appear based on a number in another column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In Google Sheets:
In column B, I want to display a certain word on each line, based on the value of column A.

B2 gets it value from A2, B3 gets it value from A3 etc.

range:

> 1500 triggers the word low
>
> 1501-1950 triggers the word medium
>
> 1951 triggers the word high.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming only integers are possible I would recommend a little lookup range:

```
1500     low
1500.1   medium
1951     high
```

say named `NamedRange1`, along with a [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) formula that takes advantage of (what is sometimes risky!) inexact matching:

```
=if(A2>1951,"#N/A",vlookup(A2,NamedRange1,2))
```

in B2 and copied down to suit.

Because of the inexact matching I have added an error trap for `A` values greater than `1951`, without which they too would trigger `high`.

Comment: Thanks pnuts! Can I use the same formula for the whole column, or do I need to copy/paste it to each box in the column, and modify it according to the row? And I guess NamedRange1 is where I put my own words for the range? sorry, google sheet novice with high demands :-)

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I manage to implement it, see the logic behind it now!